# std::fill outside loop very very slow compared with value added in loop

Tags: c++, performance, fill

the following code is a busy loop. I give below two logically equivalent pieces of code, one performs so much more slowly than the other that it is not usable. I would have expected it to be the faster as it replaces individual push backs by a fill statement across a whole range.

In practice the difference is beyond belief (I attach screen shots of the profiler output). I am using the most recent version of C++ on VS2019 in a project with default console programme settings. Can anyone explain; I wonder if it is a caching issue? When enabled, the  line

```
'''
std::fill(degrees.begin() + bound, degrees.begin() + upper_bound, d);
'''
```

takes 84% of the runtime whereas

```
'''
degrees.push_back(d);
'''
```

takes 3%.

```
'''
        for (DEG d = curr_degree + 1; d <= desired_degree; ++d)
        {
            KEY bound = (KEY)hall_set.size();
            KEY j_lower = 1, j_upper = bound + 2;
            for (KEY i = 1; i <= bound; ++i) {
                auto p2 = std::equal_range(degrees.begin() + i + 1, degrees.begin() + bound + 1, d - degrees[i]);
                j_lower = p2.first - degrees.begin();
                j_upper = p2.second - degrees.begin();
                for (KEY j = j_lower; j < j_upper; ++j)
                    if (hall_set[j].first <= i)
                    {
                        PARENT parents(i, j);
                        hall_set.push_back(parents);  // at position max_key.
                        degrees.push_back(d);         // at position max_key.
                        reverse_map[parents] = (KEY)hall_set.size() - 1;
                    }
                KEY upper_bound = (KEY)hall_set.size();
                //degrees.resize(upper_bound);
                //std::fill(degrees.begin() + bound, degrees.begin() + upper_bound, d);
                ++currdegree;
            }
        }
'''
```

and

```
'''
        for (DEG d = curr_degree + 1; d <= desired_degree; ++d)
        {
            KEY bound = (KEY)hall_set.size();
            KEY j_lower = 1, j_upper = bound + 2;
            for (KEY i = 1; i <= bound; ++i) {
                auto p2 = std::equal_range(degrees.begin() + i + 1, degrees.begin() + bound + 1, d - degrees[i]);
                j_lower = p2.first - degrees.begin();
                j_upper = p2.second - degrees.begin();
                for (KEY j = j_lower; j < j_upper; ++j)
                    if (hall_set[j].first <= i)
                    {
                        PARENT parents(i, j);
                        hall_set.push_back(parents);  // at position max_key.
                        //degrees.push_back(d);         // at position max_key.
                        reverse_map[parents] = (KEY)hall_set.size() - 1;
                    }
                KEY upper_bound = (KEY)hall_set.size();
                degrees.resize(upper_bound);
                std::fill(degrees.begin() + bound, degrees.begin() + upper_bound, d);
                ++currdegree;
            }
        }
...
```

Here are the screen shopopts from the profiler:
[image]

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization turned on, or in debug mode?

Comment: +1 For Shawn. MS's debug library is very heavily loaded with checking. Sometimes painfully slow. So.....

Comment: x64 Release mode, default optimisation choices for a c++ console program in release mode.

Comment: Might be because the condition `(hall_set[j].first <= i)` is not always evaluated to `true`, hence the number of `push_back` calls is lower than the distance in `std::fill` iterators.